# What is the issubclass equivalent of isinstance in python?

Tags: python, introspection

Given an object, how do I tell if it's a class, and a subclass of a given class Foo?

e.g.

```
class Bar(Foo):
  pass

isinstance(Bar(), Foo) # => True

issubclass(Bar, Foo) # <--- how do I do that?
```

Comment: Wow, good thing you did not just try to run this in the Python interpreter, it could have totally fried your PC! ;-)

Comment: Just a note: Most times people want to check for types, what they really want to do is to check if required methods are implemented...

Comment: elzapp: this is debug code, where i want to do different things if i'm passed a regular class or a class from the ORM

Comment: @elzapp: Note that with the new Abstract Base Classes (ABCs) using issubclass becomes a practical alternative to checking for individual methods.

Comment: Good point -- never, never, never just try something in Python.  And -- above all -- never use Google to search for something.  The damage to your computer would be catastrophic.

Comment: -1 for breaking my head trying to understand how to call `issubclass(Bar, Foo)` )

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It works exactly as one would expect it to work...

```
class Foo():
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

class Bar2():
    pass

print issubclass(Bar, Foo)  # True
print issubclass(Bar2, Foo) # False
```

If you want to know if an *instance* of a class derived from a given base class, you could use:

```
bar_instance = Bar()
print issubclass(bar_instance.__class__, Foo)
```